# Speed and Memory problems when Deploying Deep Learning Model

Tags: deep-learning, classification

I need to build a deep learning model for image classifying. I need to train a deep learning model on those data and then deploying it on real machines.

In conclusion, My main problems are:

- Images are very big, which leads CUDA to memory issues. what shall I do to prevent my model running out of memory limit?
- Besides, I need a very fast inference, because the model will be used on real deploy environment. The speed is very important for timely response.

I need to solve both the 2 problems to deploy my model.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is important to reduce the size of the images. reshape them if necessary, which can significantly reduce the memory cost.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try different batch size. Becasue batch size is directly related to training and inference speed of deep learning. But I think better GPU machine card is more important for image classifying with deep learning network.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need better GPU card as deep learning is machine hungry.